# Correlation between three variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, correlation

In MATLAB, I have the following:

A, B, C are 1 x 101 row vectors. I know that for 'i' from 1 to 101, A(i), B(i), and C(i) are linearly correlated.

How can I identify the dependence between A, B, and C?

Comment: Um, I don't want to sound stupid, but what about correlating each with each other, ging you a 3x3 matrix with the autocorrelation coefficients on the diagonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the degree of correlation, you can use [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html):

```
data = [A(:) B(:) C(:)];
correlation = corrcoef(data);
```

Here's a test case that shows positive/negative correlation as well as the degree of correlation, with

```
N = 10000;
A = randn(N,1);
B =  3*A + randn(N,1);
C = -2*A + 20*randn(N,1);

correlation =

    1.0000    0.9473   -0.1005
    0.9473    1.0000   -0.0927
   -0.1005   -0.0927    1.0000
```

Comment: Ok thanks. How can I construct a linear relationship from here? corrcoef helps, but I am lacking in the statistical background.

Comment: @arabhimanachra I updated my answer. The correlation coefficient is a more suitable metric here. The `(i,j)` entry of the correlation measures correlation of variable `i` with vaeriable `j`.