# Correlation Matrix of a 1x1 Structure

Tags: matlab, correlation

I have a 1x1 data structure which contains 144 fields (i.e. each field is a 26048x1 vector (double)). I need to find the correlation matrix of this data set (showing the correlation between vectors) and at the end, I need to plot it like the figure below:

[image]

Be thankful for any idea!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correlation between three variables in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550242/correlation-between-three-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: You can transform your struct to a matrix using `struct2cell` and `cell2mat`